# Use connection string variable within DoCmd.TransferDatabase

Tags: vba, ms-access, odbc

I've got 2 modules (one contains a DSN connection string for an ODBC (FoxPro) database and the other one contains some code to get the dat). My goal is to use a connection string (based on a DSN connection stored within Windows) for all connections I need instead coding the same string over and over again.

Here is what I've got so far:

first module

```
Option Compare Database
Public Const ConnectionStringEasyProd As String = """ODBC;DSN=EasyProd PPS;DataDirectory=M:\;SERVER=NotTheServer;Compression= ;DefaultType=FoxPro;Rows=False;Language=OEM;AdvantageLocking=ON;Locking=Record;MemoBlockSize=64;MaxTableCloseCache=5;ServerTypes=6;TrimTrailingSpaces=False;EncryptionType=RC4;FIPS=False"""
```

second module

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, ConnectionStringEasyProd, acTable, "BEL_PLZ", "Belegungsplaetze_Temp", False
```

After starting the sub I get an error 13.
Guess defining the connection string as a string is wrong because I need a variant, right?

Comment: Why the triple quotes in the connection string? That's just wrong... Also, if you use a DSN and want us to judge the connection string, share the DSN specification.

Comment: triple quote because the Connection string needs to be within quotes to work with the TransferDatabase command.

Isn't the DSN name sufficient? Can't share it because of company security restrictions

Comment: That's just not true. You might want to check [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferdatabase). A proper call would look something like `DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database",    ConnectionStringEasyProd, acTable, "BEL_PLZ", "Belegungsplaetze_Temp"` without the triple quotes. If you have an error in the DSN, that could also lead to this error, but it's likely your plain wrong TransferDatabase call.

Comment: Better try single quotes to define string for setting constant. And assign parameters to correct argument position.

Comment: You were right June7, removed 2 quotes and "ODBC;". Now the second module looks like this ----> "ODBC;" & ConnectionStringEasyProd <---- and that's working, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Moritz - Please consider posting your solution as an answer so that others may benefit.